# How to detect breakpoint is hitting a function in trace32 using lauterbach script?

Tags: scripting, trace32, lauterbach

I am modifing the lauterbach script.
I need to check if the breakpoint is hitting correctly on the same breakpoint which I wanted to hit.

Task_func has a runanble Runnable_Func

I used this piece;

```
IF STRing.ComPare(sYmbol.FUNCTION(PP()),"*\Runnable_Func")
PRINT "NICEWORK"
ELSE
PRINT "BADCODE"
```

But in this case I am getting the true value for the owned function(Task_Func in this case).

Can I check the same way breakpoint for the runnables
I need the true condition for Runnable_Func.
Another try which I did is

```
 &pc=r(pc)
```

`&call=address.offset(Task_NoAr_Schd_50msfunc\10)`

```
IF (&pc==&call)
```

is any other options anyone aware?

Cheers,
Nilesh

Comment: Do you know the address of your breakpoint? It is a program breakpoint, right?

Comment: Yes I can extract the address of breakpoint !

Comment: What was wrong with your idea `IF (Register(PP)==ADDRESS.OFFSET(Task_NoAr_Schd_50msfunc\10))` ? That idea looks rather good to me....

Comment: it executes corretcly but at the sub function level I can not check the called functions name rather than I have to check the line number where it has stopped. I expect that script might have some thing to detect the name inside the function which is called inside the main function! Never the less this ADDRESS.OFFSET is best option.

Comment: As you have figured out already, with `PRINT sYmbol.FUNCTION(PP())` you'll get the name of the function where execution has stopped. You can get it's caller by first executing `FRAME.Up` and then  `PRINT sYmbol.FUNCTION(PP())` (You can also use `FRAME.Up` several times to go up higher in the call stack)

Comment: I am still not sure if I understand your question.... But, maybe `PRINT sYmbol.SOURCEFILE(PP())` and `PRINT sYmbol.SOURCELINE(PP())` is whant you need?